# What would happen if blades are not pitched correctly on a propeller blades?

Tags: propeller

What would happen on a 6 blade propeller if each blade opposite another was pitched in completely the opposite direction.

Comment: This seems entirely hypothetical, and we're focused on more practical matters.

Comment: Aren't they mechanically linked via some gearing in the propeller hub, thus that could never happen?

Comment: This document shows how a McCauley 2-blade propeller has its pitch controlled, 6-blade would likely be similar, but just more of it.  https://www.airtreknorth.com/uploads/4/7/2/4/4724302/von_klip_tip_cs_propeller.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "completely opposite direction"? perpendicular? each blade 60° more pitched?

Answer (score 4):

For a start, whoever built the propeller would get investigated for possible drug/alcohol impairment on the job.

In terms of trying to run the propeller, it would generate a lot of noise (from turbulence of the blades running in "reverse pitch", possibly stalled relative to the airflow induced by the previous blade) and very little or no thrust.  If it's on a piston engine (or electric motor, assuming a model aircraft or drone case), the engine/motor is likely to overheat after a short time due to lack of cooling airflow.

Finally, it's possible vibration induced by the noise-causing turbulence could lead to a structural failure of either the propeller itself, the engine/motor, or the engine/motor mounts.